# How do I install chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I install google chrome in Raspbian? Ive tried downloading it from the internet but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no available chromium in repository.
You should follow this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195

Comment: This worked for me on raspian stretch, based on that article:

wget -qO - http://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/kusti8/chromium-rpi jessie main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser -y

I think that people are searching and only getting Jessie answers.

Answer (score -2):

First open up terminal, then paste the following commands in order:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

^ This updates the available packages + the versions

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

^ This actually upgrades the packages (it's good practice to run both of the commands before installing any new packages)

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

^ This installs Chromium, the open source project by Google that Google Packages into Google Chrome (they are the same thing)

That is it! Hope I helped!

Comment: `E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate`